# Insert results of subquery into table with a constant

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The outline of the tables in question are as follows:

I have a table, lets call it join, that has two columns, both foreign keys to other tables. Let's call the two columns userid and buildingid so join looks like

```
+--------------+
| join         |
|--------------|
|userid        |
|buildingid    |
+--------------+
```

I basically need to insert a bunch of rows into this table.  Each user will be assigned to multiple buildings by having multiple entries in this table.  So user 13 might be assigned to buildings 1, 2, and 3 by the following

```
13 1
13 2
13 3
```

I'm trying to figure out how to do this in a query if the building numbers are constant, that is, I'm assigning a group of people to the same buildings.  Basically, (this is wrong) I want to do

```
insert into join (userid, buildingid) values ((select userid from users), 1)
```

Does that make sense?  I've also tried using

```
select 1
```

The error I'm running into is that the subquery returns more than one result.  I also attempted to create a join, basically with a static select query that was also unsuccessful.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Almost! When you want to insert to values of a query, don't try to put them in the `values` clause. `insert` can take a `select` as an argument for the values!

```
insert into join (userid, buildingid)
select userid, 1 from users
```

Also, in the spirit of learning more, you can create a table that doesn't exist by using the following syntax:

```
select userid, 1 as buildingid
into join
from users
```

That only works if the table doesn't exist, though, but it's a quick and dirty way to create table copies!

Comment: Dough! So close!  That was it!  Just as a point of clarification, is it possible to chain multiple select statements to do multiple insertions as you can when you do use the values clause?

Comment: Not in T-SQL, unfortunately. If you ever use MySQL, that supports chaining `values` together. What you *can* do is `insert into join (userid, buildingid) select * from (select 1, 1 union all select 2, 1 union all select 3, 1 ...)`.